# Running under the profiler 20x faster

Tags: visual-studio-2015, profiling, resharper

This makes absolutely no sense. But I've had 2 other people look at this and they see nothing different that would explain this.

I have a command line application that I run from VisualStudio. It's C# with a lot of it .NET code created from Java sources via IKVM. From VisualStudio I click run and the app takes about 50 seconds to run.

From VisualStudio I then tell the ReSharper profiler to run it under the profiler - and it takes a bit over 2 seconds.

In both cases the app is creating reports and the reports are created. In both cases I'm running the same project from VisualStudio so no difference in command line, files run, etc.

This makes no sense. Yet it's happening. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Can you share this code? Are you running each method individually in resharper or the entire command line application?

Comment: @cptwonton unfortunately no, can't share it (and it's massive). I'm running the full command line app from start to done (& exited).

Comment: strange. I'd try adding a console.readkey(); as the first statement in your console app's main method. then go to VS->Resharper->Profile, and set up your profiler but use attach to process. Once it's attached, wait a bit, and then hit the key in your console. Let it run. Compare runtime to the same without attaching. This means your app will run standalone in both cases (otherwise, resharper will spawn this on its own process and do whatever with it).

Answer (score 0):

I considered deleting this question because the answer shows rampant stupidity on my part. But I figure better to post it here for others that face the same problem.

I was running under the debugger. If I run from the command line, then the speed is equal.

Comment: very funny ;) resharper isn't as intuitive as some may be lead to believe. but yes, resharper certainly doesn't automagically speed up an application, although it can be used to speed up an app.